# App crashes when I try to display user's Photo Library in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My ViewController looks like: Camera View on top and Photo Gallery on the bottom, like in Instagram.

When I try to load user's image library and display it on UICollectionView, app crashes with the `Memory Warning`. How can I prevent it and improve my function?

My function:

```
func getImagesFromLibrary(from: Int = 0, to: Int = 5, completion: (loaded: Bool) -> Void) {
    if images.count > 0 {
        for i in from..<to {
            let asset: PHAsset = self.images[i] as! PHAsset
            let imageFetchOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()

            self.imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 75, height: 75), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: imageFetchOptions, resultHandler: { (image: UIImage?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in
                if (image != nil) {
                    if let img = image {
                        self.croppedImagesArray[i] = img
                        self.imagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        completion(loaded: true)
    } else {
        print("Images Empty")
    }
}
```

and I call it via:

```
        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
        print("GRANTED")
        self.getImagesFromLibrary { (loaded) in
            if loaded {
                print("Images Count: \(self.images.count)")

                if self.images.count > 5 {
                    print("Second part")
                    self.getImagesFromLibrary(5, to: self.images.count / 2, completion: { (loaded) in
                        if loaded {
                            self.getImagesFromLibrary(self.images.count / 2, to: self.images.count, completion: { (loaded) in })
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, now I have in my gallery 300 images. It's a lot and that's why my app crashes on loading process.

How can I solve it? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you simply hold too much images in memory, and thus get a memory warning.
When you get a memory warning, iOS gives you the opportunity to release data that are easily be recreated. If you don’t do so, your app can be terminated anytime.

So the question is if you really need to hold all those images in memory.
If so, you have a real problem, and iOS might not be the right platform for your app.
If not, e.g. if you want to show only part of the loaded images at a time, you should use placeholder images that are shown when a image that should be shown is not in memory, download the image, and replace the placeholder by the real image as soon as it has been downloaded.

One way to store images so that you won’t get a memory warning is to use a `NSCache` <[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/)>, which is something like a `NSMutableDictionary`, in which you can store images, but images which have not been used long will be cleared automatically when memory becomes tight. So if you have to display an image, you could first display the placeholder, and then try to load it from the cache, and if this fails, to download it.
Of course, there are also frameworks that do the caching automatically for you, e.g. `AFNetworking` <[Github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)>.

Answer (score 0):

By default requestImageForAsset: is asynchronous. The code you have written will immediately fire off requests for all 300 images, and as you see run out of memory. So the code where you load 5 images, and then the first half, and then the second half is all just being run at once.

I would recommend in UICollection cellForRowAtIndexPath: you call self.imageManager.requestImageForAsset(self.images[indexPath.item] .... and set the UImageView for that cell in the result handler block. No need to preload all 300 images, the user may never even scroll to see them all. And someone else may have 3000 images or more.

Also in your result handler your calling collectionView reloadData every time an image is fetched, even reloading when the image that was fetched isn't even currently displayed. Use reloadItemsAtIndexPath: to just load the cell associated with the image.